# Running .NET 3.0 SOAP client on Mono 2.6.7-5ubuntu3

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, mono, soap-client

I'd like to run SOAP client on UBUNTU but I finally get error *"Client endpoint configuration '**' *was not found in 0 endpoints"*.
Looks like *client.dll.config* configuration file was not loaded. How to do with *mono*?

Answer (score 0):

Probably

```
<system.serviceModel>
```

node is missing in your web.config
(assuming it's a web project).